# manyToManyField question

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

Hay guys, I'm writing a simple app which logs recipes.

I'm working out my models and have stumbled across a problem

My Dish models needs to have many Ingredients. This is no problem because i would do something like this

```
ingredients = models.ManyToManyfield(Ingredient)
```

No problems, my dish now can have many ingrendients.

However, the problem is that the ingredient needs to come in different quantities.

I.E 4 eggs, 7 tablespoons sugar

My Ingredient Model is very simple at the moment

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
```

How would i go about work out this problem? What fields would i need to add, would i need to use a 'through' attribute on my ManyToManyfield to solve this problem?

Comment: Read [this qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942458/django-complex-modelling), i think it quite similar to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the right answer with a "through" table ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany )

**Model**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='Components')

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

class Components(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    quantity = models.DecimalField()
```

You can put unit of quantity (gram, kilo, tablespoon, etc) on Ingredient level, but I think it is better on Ingredients level (for example you can have 1 recipe with 10 Cl of milk but one other with 1L ... So "different" units for a same ingredient.

**Data Creation**

By Dish you mean Recipe right ? If you have a look to previous link (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany), they give you a good example (based on the beatles). 
Basically :

1.Create a Recipe:

```
cake=Recipe.objects.create(name="Simple Cake")
```

2.Create several Ingredient (if they doesn't already exist from a previous recipe ;)):

```
egg = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Egg")
milk = Ingredient.objects.create(name="milk")
```

3.Create the relationship:

```
cake_ing1 = Components.objects.create(recipe=cake, ingredient=egg,quantity = 2)  
cake_ing2 = Components.objects.create(recipe=cake, ingredient=milk,quantity = 200)
```

and so on. Plus, I'm now quite sure that unit should go to Components level, with a default unit as "piece" (that would be for yours eggs ...), and would be something like "mL" for milk.

**Data Access**

In order to get ingredients (Components) of a recipe just do :

```
cake = Recipe.objects.get(name = "Simple Cake")
components_cake = Components.objects.get(recipe = cake)
```

Comment: How would i add another ingredient after the initial Dish object has been created?

Comment: My Ingredients model is called Components and looks pretty much the same as that model. I want to create a Dish Obj, then add lots of Ingrentients. Usually i would do Dish.ingredients.add(Ingredient Obj), but i need these extra fields. Would i create a Component object and then do Dish.ingredients.add(Component Obj) ?

Comment: I just add more informations in my former post (because not enough space in comment !)

Comment: ok thats all fine, i can now add more ingredients to a dish (recipe). Now when i do Dish.ingredients.all() . cannot access the Components properties. So i cannot do Dish.ingredients.all()[0].quantity because it just returns a ingredient obj, not a component obj.

Comment: Any ideas on the above question?

Comment: I add some comments about how to access data, hope it helps !